# Optimal stopping problem with restricted stopping times

Tags: measure-theory, markov-chains, stopping-times, optimal-control

Consider that you have some ergodic, time-homogenous Markov process $(X_n)_{n \ge 0}$ taking values in a finite space $S$.
To solve
$$
g(N, x)
=
\sup_{\tau \le N} E \left[
f(X_\tau)
\mid 
X_0 = x
\right]
$$
one may use the value equations
$$
v(n, x) = \max \left\{ f(x), E \left[ v(n+1, X_1) \mid X_0 = x \right] \right\}, n = 1, \ldots, N-1, \, v(N,x) = f(x)
$$
and find an optimal solution by the relationship $v(0,x) = g(N, x)$.
In the infinite horizon case
$$
g(\infty, x)
=
\sup_{\tau} E \left[
f(X_\tau)
\mid 
X_0 = x
\right]
$$
I know that you similarly deploy the value function.
But what I have been wondering is if it possible to restrict the stopping times to being in a subset of values $A \subset S$ and then find the optimal stopping time amongst these?
That is to consider the problem
$$
\sup_{\tau \in C} E \left[
f(X_\tau)
\mid 
X_0 = x
\right]
$$
where
$$
\tau \in C_A \iff 
\tau \stackrel{a.s.}{<} \infty, X_\tau \stackrel{a.s.}{\in} A
$$
Any papers or links are much appreciated!